# Executable Spring Boot jar does not resolve views

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm experiencing problems building an executable spring boot jar file.

configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RootConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RootConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class Index {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootTest2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Test page!
  </body>
</html>
```

structure:

[image: structure]

Starting from Idea:

[image: idea]

Starting executable jar from command line:

[image]

How to resolve such a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some limitations in the JSP support.

> 1. With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard
>      container (not limited to, but including Tomcat). An executable jar
>      will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.
> 2. With Jetty it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to any standard
>      container.

You might want to look at this example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp)

[Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15942646)

Comment: Edited my answer.